# yii2-usuario: How to override a login view?

Tags: php, view, yii2, overriding

Some time ago I developed a Yii2 app with Dektrium-based login form. As it has been deprecated I moved to 2Amigos' yii2-usuario, but now my own `login.php` view is not rendering at all being automagically replaced by yii2-usuario's.

[According to yii2-usuario](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing/overriding-views/), I should override this login view using the following:

```
'components' => [
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => [
                '@Da/User/resources/views' => '@app/views/user'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Supposedly this should favour any own-made view only replacing them with yii2-usuario's views when no own-made view is found, but in my case Yii2 throws the following:

```
yii\base\ViewNotFoundException: The view file does not exist: /myapp/vendor/2amigos/yii2-usuario/src/User/resources/views/_alert.php in /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php:233
Stack trace:
#0 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile()
#1 /myapp/views/user/security/login.php(27): yii\base\View->render()
#2 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(347): require('/usr/local/shar...')
#3 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(257): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile()
#4 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile()
#5 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(407): yii\base\View->render()
#6 /myapp/vendor/2amigos/yii2-usuario/src/User/Controller/SecurityController.php(172): yii\base\Controller->render()
#7 [internal function]: Da\User\Controller\SecurityController->actionLogin()
#8 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#9 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#10 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#11 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#12 /myapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#13 /myapp/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround copying `resources/views/shared/_alert.php` one level up but I feel this should not have to be this way.

LATER: ah I noticed I have this in `login.php`:

```
<?= $this->render('/_alert', ['module' => Yii::$app->getModule('user')]) ?>
```

So I just changed to:

```
<?= $this->render('/shared/_alert', ['module' => Yii::$app->getModule('user')]) ?>
```